Epson SDK Issue (Android)
I am trying to print to one epson printer from multiple devices. It prints for the first device, but then crashes the application on the other device(s). Below is my code. The toast returns the number 3, but i cannot figure out what error that represents. Any help would be much appreciated.
private void printToKitchen() throws Epos2Exception {

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("printers", 0);
        String kitchenPrinterIP = mPrefs.getString("kitchenPrinterIP", "default_value_if_variable_not_found");
        if (!kitchenPrinterIP.equals("default_value_if_variable_not_found")) {
            kitchenPrinter.connect("TCP:" + kitchenPrinterIP, Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
            kitchenPrinter.beginTransaction();
            kitchenPrinter.sendData(Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
            kitchenPrinter.endTransaction();
            kitchenPrinter.clearCommandBuffer();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bar Printer not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


try {
            printToKitchen();
        } catch (Epos2Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + e.getErrorStatus() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


Rather than showing a Toast, use Log.e() to log the exception and its stack trace, as that may give you more information.

The error number 3 seems to be an EPOS2_ERR_DEVICE_BUSY error from the Epson ePOS SDK. Usually occurs when the printer is already being used by another application or device. Try the following:
Always disconnect from printer after printing. If that doesn’t fix the problem, add a retry logic with a delay if the printer is busy. You may also consider implementing a queue system to handle multiple print jobs by storing print jobs in a queue, process them sequentially, and add appropriate delays between jobs.
Check your printer settings and be sure the printer is configured to allow multiple connections. Ensure network settings are correct and the printer firmware is up to date.
